# How can I merge two documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, merge

I have two documents in one collection.

```
{id: 1, list_data: [1, 2, 4, 5]}
{id: 1, list_data: [2, 5, 8, 9]}
```

I want merge those data into one document.

```
{id: 1, list_data: [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9]}
```

How can I do this job?
Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to MongoDB documentation

> Aggregation operations group values from multiple documents together,
>   and can perform a variety of operations on the grouped data to return
>   a single result.

Please refer the aggregation query as mentioned below .

```
db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $unwind: {
                path:'$list_data'
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $group: {
              _id:{id:'$id'},
              list_data:{$addToSet:'$list_data'}
            }
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $project: {
                '_id.id':1,
                "list_data":1
            }
        },

    ]



);
```

In above query document is processed through multiple stages of  aggregation pipeline

Comment: what if I have 

I have three documents in one collection.

{id: 1, list_data: [1, 2, 4, 5]}
{id: 1, list_data: [2, 5, 8, 9]}
{id: 2, list_data: []}

and I want the result as 
{id: 1, list_data: [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9]}
{id: 2, list_data: []}

then how I can achieve this?